# Why I can't get right answer?

Tags: python

[Code on Github](https://github.com/Sennacheribest/4Share/blob/master/compare.py)

A baby programmer seeking for help, please.
What went wrong in my code if anyone can help?

A very simple python program to compare two numbers using functions

```
from sys import exit

def main():
    check()
    compare(x, y)

def check():
    # prompt user for two numbers
    x = input("x: ")
    y = input("y: ")

    # apply sanity check
    if x.isnumeric() == False and y.isnumeric() == False:
        print("Usage: only real numbers are accepted.")
        exit(1)
    else:
        return x, y

def compare(x, y):
    # TODO
    if x < y:
        return print("x is smaller than y")
    elif x > y:
        return print("x is greater than y")
    else:
        return print("They are the same!")

main()
```

Comment: Please don't put links to the code. Instead copy-paste the code in the question itself with a sample input and expected output.

Comment: @tdelaney ah... I just always assume it's an image. I'll delete the comment... thanks for editing.

Comment: You are checking your input are numeric, good. Then you must transform then INT type before comparing them. here you're doing "123" < "456", when you want 123 < 456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If not convert x, y to int, it will compare x, y as string(dictionary order)
2. you should check x , y is number by or, not and

```
from sys import exit

def main():
    x, y = check()
    compare(x, y)

def check():
    # prompt user for two numbers
    x = input("x: ")
    y = input("y: ")

    # apply sanity check
    if x.isnumeric() is False or y.isnumeric() is False:
        print("Usage: only real numbers are accepted.")
        exit(1)
    else:
        return x, y

def compare(x, y):
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    # TODO
    if x < y:
        return print("x is smaller than y")
    elif x > y:
        return print("x is greater than y")
    else:
        return print("They are the same!")

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a common mistake.

1- You have made two functions `check()` and `compare()` and you are working on x and y in both of them. But any variable which is defined in a function has scope in that function only. So, you can use x and y only in the check function as they are defined there.To use variables in multiple functions, you can declare them as global. Then the variables can be accessed from any function.

2- Another mistake here is that you are passing x and y as arguments to compare function, but as x and y are only available for check to use, so it is giving error. I have removed the arguments and have worked with the global approach instead.

See the below code:

```
from sys import exit

def main():
    check()
    compare()

def check():
    #initialising x and y as global
    global x, y
    # prompt user for two numbers
    x = input("x: ")
    y = input("y: ")

    # apply sanity check
    if x.isnumeric() == False and y.isnumeric() == False:
        print("Usage: only real numbers are accepted.")
        exit(1)
    else:
        return x, y

def compare():
    global x, y
    if x < y:
        return print("x is smaller than y")
    elif x > y:
        return print("x is greater than y")
    else:
        return print("They are the same!")

main()
```

The output for x = 5 and y = 3 as test case is-

```
x is greater than y
```